# Edit Refresh Time for Google Data Studio Report

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have a report which fetches data from a BigQuery Table. I need to refresh the report after the job for the BigQuery table is completed everyday. I am aware that I can set the Data Studio freshness (4,12,24 hours) but can I control the time of refresh, for example at 6 am of my time zone?

I checked the options for data freshness but could not find the refresh time option.

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively, you can [refresh report](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020039?hl=en) data manually and also turn off the predictive cache. Fetching the results directly from the sources will incur query charges for [on-demand pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#on_demand_pricing).

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the on-demand pricing. However, is there a way to schedule refresh from Data Studio by choosing  both time and refresh rate ?

Comment: I don't see that this is possible at the moment.

Comment: I'm also in need of scheduling the refresh. I haven't found a solution yet.